# Placing a full width image in a text layout that occupies half width?

Tags: floats

I have a latex document where each page is split into the left and right parts, where the text is written first in the left part and then starts in the right part. I have a scenario where I need to place an image that fills the entire width of the page, with the text occupying the rest of the space in the page with the same left right format.

The issue I have is that setting the `[width=\paperwidth]` makes the text float on top of the image, on the right side. I am not able to find a way to fix this. Looking for guidance on the same.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{a}
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{images/flow_chart.png}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Full Field spot Diagram, convex fft(a), concave fft(b) and eliptical fft (c). Scale : 1mm/unit, Total simulation image area : 10mm x 10mm}
\label{fig:Algorithm}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. We need to know what you have done, it is almost impossible to give a precise advice without knowing your preamble, the minimum set of packages that reproduces your question and what you've tried. Without MWEs we can sometimes give some vague advice.

Comment: Thank you. added.

Comment: In a two-column document, the `figure*` and `table*` environments compose figures and tables that span the width of both columns.

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed it!